# apache server fail to start in ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2

when I am trying to start or stop or restart the apache server in Ubuntu. It's going to fail and no error is showing. Only following is displayed:

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
```

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd stop
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
```

Comment: try executing `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`, what error messages are logged there?

Answer (score 2):

From [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html):

> You can check your configuration files for syntax errors without starting the server by using `apachectl` configtest or the `-t` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files (usually in `/var/log/apache2/` on Ubuntu) and move your question to Serverfault.com, because this is not programming related.